# optimization based on alignment requirements

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization, memory-alignment

According to [[basic.align]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.align#1)

> Object types have alignment requirements ([basic.fundamental],
>   [basic.compound]) which place restrictions on the addresses at which
>   an object of that type may be allocated.

I would expect a C++ compiler is allowed to assume that any pointer to T points to a correctly aligned T.

e.g. (if alignof(int) == 4)

```
int* p = /* ... */
auto val = p[0];
if ((reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p) & 3) != 0) {
   // assumed to be unreachable
}
```

However, testing GCC and clang in compiler explorer, I don't see either of them making this assumption. **Even if I dereference the pointer** (which surely would cause UB if it was not correctly aligned) this pointer-value assumption is not made.

I recognise that the mapping of pointers to integer values is implementation defined, and that perhaps the compiler has a mapping other than what this code assumes (though, I don't think so).

I also recognise that there may be a lot of code in production would break by making this assumption, explaining why it's not currently done by these compilers.

My question is: **According to the standard, would it be a valid assumption a compiler could make?**

If not, please cite the standard!

EDIT: clarified that the pointer is dereferenced.

EDIT2: say alignof() (instead of sizeof())

Comment: The standard does not prohibit using the alignment bits of pointers to store custom data.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant. Surely you cannot dereference a pointer that's incorrectly aligned, so you would have to mask out those bits before using the pointer

Comment: For historical reasons the alignment requirements are a bit soft for x86 processors. The 8088 in the original PC had an 8-bit memory bus, so didn't really care much about alignment. Its successors still accept unaligned access, perhaps with a slightly degraded performance - but it still works.

Comment: Even the mapping itself is implementation defined. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#4 You should check the implementation manual.

Comment: I think the fundamental underlying question is - is misaligned access really UB or is it implementation-defined?

Comment: I don't think this is controversial. undefined-sanitizer (ubsan) checks for unaligned access, and there's this: https://pzemtsov.github.io/2016/11/06/bug-story-alignment-on-x86.html

Comment: Why talk about sizeof when you mean alignof?

Comment: The compiler isn't _required_ to make use of any arbitrary assumption it is permitted to make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes compilers *may* assume the pointer is properly aligned.

Let us assume for the time being there's a function `is_aligned` which tests whether the address pointed to by a pointer has proper alignment for its type.

```
int* p = /* ... */
auto val = p[0];
if (is_aligned(p)) {
   // assumed to be unreachable
}
```

Will then be true. We deduce this from [[basic.life]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1)

> The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained [...]

Thus no object that has improper alignment exists. [It then follows](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3) that the pointer is either a null pointer, invalid or pointing to an object of another type.

Accessing through a null pointer is illegal, [access through invalid pointers](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4) is also illegal, and so is [access to an object of another type](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)<sup>†</sup>, which makes access through misaligned pointers UB.

<sub>† with exception of `unsigned char`, `char` and `std::byte`</sub>

Comment: >> Yes compilers _may_ assume the pointer is properly aligned.

This does not address the question DO THEY?
Does the C++ standard make any reference to this or provide any way to find out what alignment the compiler assumes?

What I have learned that alignof() indicates the alignment which the compiler guarantees in laying out memory attempting to optimise memory but that does not prohibit dereferencing pointers not aligned to alignof().

`char src[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu";
 *(long long*)(src+1) = *(long long*)(src+3);`

Works on VS2019 and g++ 6.3; both alignof() = 8

Comment: @Questaware Isn't the entire post about how the standard says it's UB? Undefined doesn't mean your code must crash, it means, literally, you have no guarantees what does happen. I don't know to what degree compilers exploit this.

Comment: Is this not rather unusual?
This is something which I can exploit to literally speed up code by a factor of 20 and which is supported by the two most important compilers but the standard says it is undefined behaviour (does it actually say this) IS THE COMMITTEE PROUD OF THIS? 

It would make things much better if there was a builtin requiredalign(T).

Comment: @Questaware I have no clue what you're talking about. Neither is this the correct place for a discussion.